# Bucle infinito por cURL php

Tags: php, curl, depuración

**EDICIÓN:**
Por alguna razón el código entra en un bucle infinito, intuyo que es porque no procesa bien los atributos estáticos. El dilema está en que depurándolos por separado y eliminando el `curl_exec` sí se procesan bien, es ejecutar la acción de cURL y entra en el bucle.

Dejo aquí los logs que corroboran mi idea:

> [Sun Dec 31 00:26:41.219540 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 27696:tid 636] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

> [Sun Dec 31 00:27:32.681524 2023] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 27696:tid 6240] AH00326: Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting

Les pongo en contexto, estoy intentando hacer una especie de **depurador** que verifique `request` de un tipo predefinido. El problema está en que se queda en un **bucle infinito** de transacciones haciendo que mi servidor localhost evidentemente se quede pillado.

A modo de solución, he creado un atributo estático con el fin de que cuando se actualice por primera vez lo detecte el código y emita una instrucción de `die` junto con el código de respuesta de la primera transacción también guardada en un `atributo estático`.

Imagino que hay otras maneras mucho mejor de llevar a cabo este tipo de depuraciones, pero me gustaría seguir el formato escogido, ya por pura cabezonería.

Código de la página a debuggear:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/Classes/DebugTrace.php";

    $e = new DebugTrace();

    $e->setEnviroment();
```

Código del método y atributos estáticos de DebugTrace

```
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Interfaces/usefulMethods.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Constants/constants.php';

class DebugTrace implements usefulMethods{

    public static $contador = 0;
    public static $content;

   
    public function setEnviroment(){

        if(self::$contador != 0) die(var_dump(self::$content));

        $data = "exampleData";

        $ch = curl_init(debugMode['url']);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, debugMode['method']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->normalizer(debugMode['customHeader']));

        self::$contador = 1;

       $response = curl_exec($ch);

    
            self::$content = curl_errno($ch) ? "ERROR" : $response;
        
        

        
        curl_close($ch);

        return;


    }
```

La clase tiene más contenido, pero no es el causante del bucle infinito.

Comment: Hola. Analizando el código que nos muestras no veo ningún bucle infinito. ¿En qué consiste exactamente dicho bucle? ¿Dónde lo detectas? ¿Qué mensajes de error ves en el log de errores? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano listo, ya he añadido los detalles. Lo único que no he mencionado es el bucle. Básicamente se queda infinitamente hasta que el localhost se queda sin recursos. Otra cosa a añadir es que no lo puedo parar desde XAMPP, debo de matar el proceso como tal

Comment: Sigo sin ver el famoso bucle del que hablas. No hay ningún bucle en el código de la pregunta, simplemente una clase con un método. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y agrega el bucle problemático. Quizá el problema está en la parte donde llamas a la clase. ¿Hay un bucle ahí? Pues muestra esa parte del código.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de resolverlo. Simplemente es que por lo visto una petición de tipo cURL no trata correctamente las variables estáticas, es decir, por cada petición cURL reinicia el conteo, haciendo que siempre sea 0 y creándose una sucesión de conexiones abiertas que provoca ese bucle infinito. Lo he solucionado usando un archivo JSON como auxiliar; voy a añadir la respuesta y marcar la pregunta como solucionada, gracias!

Comment: Guardar una variable en una no-instancia, es prácticamente una variable global. En general, es riesgoso mezclar contextos, es decir, leer variables estáticas desde contextos no-estáticos puede producir resultados inesperados debido a cómo el [*Enlace estático tardío*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) de php resuelve a la clase. Por principio, un valor estático no debería cambiar, debería ser... estático.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema se encontraba en que cada transacción de cURL hace que el conteo del atributo estático se reinicie, por lo que, no importa cuantos chequeos previos pongas que la ejecución de cURL va a seguir abriendo conexiones hasta saturar el servidor.

A modo de solución he creado un archivo `JSON auxiliar` que contiene un objeto `boolean` llamado "debugged" (`true` si ha sido depurado y `false` en caso contrario).

Dejo por aquí el código por si a alguien le es útil:

```
   public function twoInOne() : void{
 
    $readJSON = json_decode(file_get_contents("./Classes/JSON/metaNet.json"), true);

    $readJSON["debugged"] = true;

    file_put_contents("./Classes/JSON/metaNet.json",json_encode($readJSON));

}


public function getJson(){
    return json_decode(file_get_contents("./Classes/JSON/metaNet.json"), true);
}

public function setEnviroment(){

    $data = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    $ch = curl_init(debugMode['url']);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, debugMode['method']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->normalizer(debugMode['customHeader']));

    $this->twoInOne();

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

   $this->inference = curl_errno($ch) ? "ERROR" : $response;
    
    curl_close($ch);

    return $this->inference;


}
```